# Crash during drawAtPoint, code works on iPad Air, iPad simulator, crashes on iPad 1 and iPad mini

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, uiimage

I have some code that's trying to render a png to a graphics context.  The code works fine in all simulators, and works fine on an iPad Air.  But when I run it on an iPad mini or an iPad one, I see the following crash when running it while hooked up to xCode:

`` ImageIO`ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit:
    0x36f27c70:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
    0x36f27c72:  add    r7, sp, #0xc
    0x36f27c74:  push.w {r8, r10, r11}
    0x36f27c78:  ldr    r1, [r0]
    0x36f27c7a:  ldr    r2, [r0, #0xc]
    0x36f27c7c:  cmp.w  r2, r1, lsl #2
    0x36f27c80:  blo    0x36f27d06                ; ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit + 150
    0x36f27c82:  ldr    r3, [r0, #0x18]
    0x36f27c84:  lsls   r2, r1, #0x2
    0x36f27c86:  cmp    r3, r2
    0x36f27c88:  blo    0x36f27d06                ; ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit + 150
    0x36f27c8a:  ldr    r2, [r0, #0x4]
    0x36f27c8c:  cmp    r2, #0x0
    0x36f27c8e:  beq    0x36f27d06                ; ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit + 150
    0x36f27c90:  bic    lr, r1, #0x7
    0x36f27c94:  ldr    r3, [r0, #0x8]
    0x36f27c96:  ldr.w  r12, [r0, #20]
    0x36f27c9a:  sub.w  r4, r1, lr
    0x36f27c9e:  asrs   r5, r1, #0x3
    0x36f27ca0:  mov    r6, r12
    0x36f27ca2:  mov    r8, r3
    0x36f27ca4:  cbz    r5, 0x36f27cbe            ; ImageIO_ABGR_TO_ARGB_8Bit + 78
    0x36f27ca6:  mov    r8, r3
    0x36f27ca8:  mov    r9, r5
    0x36f27caa:  mov    r6, r12
    0x36f27cac:  vld4.8 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r8]! 
    0x36f27cb0:  vswp   d0, d2
    0x36f27cb4:  vst4.8 {d0, d1, d2, d3}, [r6]!  <<--- crash on this line
    0x36f27cb8:  subs.w r9, r9, #0x1 ``

Here is the code that generates the crash:

```
NSString* imgFile = @"ShotZones.png";
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgFile];
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
float scaleShotZoneFeetToPixels = img.size.width / shotZoneCourtSizeInFeet.x;
CGRect courtRect = {{0, 0}, img.size};
CGFloat scaleFactor = screenWidth / courtRect.size.width;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
[img drawAtPoint: courtRect.origin];
```

It crashes (in a separate thread), on the call to drawAtPoint.  When stepping through the code, all the computed values are the same as when running in the xCode simulator, the UIImage is not null, etc.  Is this due to limited processing power or limited memory on the iPad?  Any thoughts as to how to fix?

Thanks!

- Dave

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: What does say the debugger?

Comment: The image is 3680x3464, about half a meg file size.  That doesn't seem insanely huge, but I'm going to try decreasing the resolution to see if that helps.  If it is memory related, it's unfortunate the simulator can't simulate the memory limits of the actual device - this stuff is much easier to debug in the simulator!

Comment: And I'm not sure what you're asking about the debugger, but the line it crashes on has an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Comment: A `UIImage` with a size of 3680x3464 will take about 50MB of memory when loaded. That's too big.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work.  It was the resolution of the image.  I decreased it by a factor of 4 and now it works.  I assume the device ran out of memory.  If anyone knows how to configure the simulator to simulate the memory capacity of an iPad 1 or mini, I'd appreciate it.  I'd like to be able to debug/test in the simulator as much as possible!